# Blender bone origin gone wrong

Tags: rigging, bones, origin

How to set the bone origin of rotation from picture 1 to picture 2? The origin of bone is set to the Grid Axis' root, not the root of the bone itself
[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you changed the origin position of a bone to something other than its head, which I thought was impossible. Regardless, can you provide a mesh-less version of the armature to study (mesh-less to protect your model, but be sure to “purge all”)?

Comment: Definitely share your file. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This is the mesh-less file. But without mesh, the rig is back to normal like the picture 2, I don't understand why [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QAJdkgAj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QAJdkgAj/)

Comment: Probably you have globally set the transform pivot point on the 3D cursor instead of the default median point (check the 4 buttons on the center of the header of the 3D window).

Comment: @joshsanfelici yes that is it. Thank you.